# client side web scrape | python |

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, client-side

How to *- web scrape at client side -* using python and its framework/library!
I am stuck in some problem.
https://angel.co/companies . this is the URL
provide me with a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). It's a really good framework for scraping. And there are lots of tutorials and community support available for that. Also, you can try [selenium](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/better-web-scraping-in-python-with-selenium-beautiful-soup-and-pandas-d6390592e251), if you need to render JS and scrape it.